# How can i get rid of this error FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, file, filenotfoundexception

```
C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication7\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied)
```

// i dont understand why this is not working, someone help me

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing and what should be working.

Comment: i have recently updated my android studio. And when i try to run hello world begineer project it showing like that

Comment: @KiranKittu Have you got the solution?

I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I tried resetting my laptop, then after it got fixed. But i wont suggest you to do that. Trying removing Android studio completly and install again.. this might fix

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissiosn problem. Run android studio as administrator. Right click on the Android Studio icon and `Run as adinistrator`

If you're on a mac use sudo to give permissions

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Shutdown Android Studio

Remove/Delete .gradle folder in the user home directory

Restart Android Studio (It will download gradle metadata and data)

Gradle build succeed

Rebuild project. Done.

Comment: Still not working i don't understand the exact problem

Comment: Above solution is working but only sometimes